# p:schedule is not displaying the day name of week under datatable?

Tags: primefaces, fullcalendar

I am using Primefaces Schedule under data table all functionalities are working fine except the day names.

```
<p:dataTable var="att" id="tbl3" value="#{seacrhEmployeeBean.empList}" rowIndexVar="row"> 
                                    <p:column headerText="Select Shifts" style="width: 65%">
                                    <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                                        <p:schedule id="schedule#{row}" value="#{att.employeeShiftDetailBean.eventModel}" 
                                                    widgetVar="myschedule#{row}" 
                                                    timeZone="UTC+05:00"
                                                    style="background-color: wheat;">

                                            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="form"
                                                    listener="#{att.employeeShiftDetailBean.onDateSelect}">
                                            </p:ajax>
                                            <p:ajax event="eventSelect" update="form"
                                                    listener="#{att.employeeShiftDetailBean.onEventSelect}">
                                            </p:ajax>
                                        </p:schedule>                                         
                                    </p:panelGrid>
                                </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

[[image]]

Comment: Maybe if you show us some code we can help you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: Thank you gehbiszumeis and Lorelorelore
i have edit the post. please check my code.

Comment: This is **not** an [mcve]. Did you try copy/pasting this (and just this) in a new empty jsf/primefaces projectd and run it? And btw, https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml works fine as does the showcase for me locally in PF 6.2, so please also post version info (always do!) and with 99.9% certainty it is cause by some css rule... Please use a browser developer tool to check this.